# C# Microsoft.Graph version 4.54.0 does not have graphClient.Groups.GetAsync( but upgrade to 5.1.0 breaks 60 statements

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, .net-7.0

```
var result = await graphClient.Groups.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "mailNickname eq '2888.001'";
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string []{ "id" };
});
```

Error   CS1061  'IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'GetAsync'

Is there a walk through for upgrading? Why is it so different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft.Graph has breaking changes between version 4.54 and version 5.

For version 4:

```
var result = await graphClient.Groups.Request()
                .Filter("mailNickname eq '2888.001'")
                .Select("id")
                .GetAsync();
```

For version 5:

```
var result = await graphClient.Groups.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "mailNickname eq '2888.001'";
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string []{ "id" };
});
```

The reason for breaking changes lies in the way how the client and models are generated. V5 of the Microsoft Graph .NET SDK moves to the new code generator Kiota.

If you have complex code then is better not to upgrade to version 5 for some time.

Quite good is to check [issues](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues) to have a detailed overview what is broken in version 5.

Docs:

[Upgrade guide](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md)

[Kiota](https://github.com/microsoft/kiota)