# Microsoft Graph API - Error Setting SingleValueExtendedProperties

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Recently, a function I wrote has stopped working.  Using the graph API, I retrieved a message via userId and messageId.  Then, I added SingleValueExtendedProperty and used Patch API to save the message back.

However, now it is throwing an exception?

*Set action is invalid for property*

What seems to be incorrect.  I am following code as:

[How to work with single-value extended properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76404941/how-to-work-with-single-value-extended-properties)

Code is as:

````
                    emailMessage.SingleValueExtendedProperties = new List<SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty>();

emailMessage.SingleValueExtendedProperties.Add
                    (
                        new SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty 
                            { 
                                Id = "String {8ECCC264-6880-4EBE-992F-8888D2EEAA1D} Name x-matter-ref", 
                                Value = reference.ToString(), 
                            }
                    );```
````

Comment: Could you please share the code? How do you set SingleValueExtendedProperty. Do you set the same property as it is in the linked issue or another one?

Comment: Added code on the main question.